# How to find top rated 3 product from each category using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have Two table : 
**1) ratemaster**
  fields are : (1) `id` (2) `userid` (3) `productid` (4) `rating`

**2) productmaster**
fields are: (1) `id` (2) `productname` (3) `category` (4)`author`

note: rating from out of 5
whenever any user give rating to any product, i am inserting record in to ratemaster table like : `1(id) 1002(userid) 995(productid) 4(rating)` 
for each user i am storing data like above.

product master contain the `categoryname` , `product name`.
now i want to get top 3 rated product from each category how would i write mysql query to achieve below output

Output :

[image: need output like below]

Comment: simple answer is join the tables, limit it to 3 order by rating descending. if you need I can write the query :)

Comment: Have you tried to make any code yourself, so we can see what you managed to do on your own.

Comment: thanks rooshan .. i tried it but not getting it.  could u please write mysql query that would be great for me

Comment: @RooshanAkthar LIMIT has no place in this query.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so (again, you haven't), provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @JigarOza I didn't notice the each category thing.

Comment: @Strawberry I am sorry, I didn't properly read the question.

Comment: top rated 3 product from each category.. check it out i put sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the PHP tag, I suggest simply calculating the rating of all entries and go on from there

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(r.rating)/COUNT(r.rating) AS rating
FROM productmaster p
INNER JOIN ratemaster r ON p.id = r.productid
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.category, rating DESC
```

This will give you a row for each product with its calculated rating (sum / number of ratings). If you are only interested in the top 3 of each category, do something like this

```
$top3 = array();
while ($row = /*..fetch logic*/) {
    if (array_key_exists($row['categoryId'], $top3)) {
        $top3[$row['categoryId']] = array();
    }
    if (count($top3[$row['categoryId']]) >= 3) {
        //top 3 for this category are found because query is ordered
        continue;
    }
    $top3[$row['categoryId']][] = array(
        //id, name, ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one-

```
SELECT a.id,a.productname,a.category,a.rating 
   FROM (SELECT prd.id,prd.productname,prd.category,rt.rating, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category != prd.category THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := prd.category AS var_category
          FROM productmaster prd 
          JOIN ratemaster rt ON rt.productid=prd.id 
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @category := '') r     
      ORDER BY prd.category,rt.rating DESC) a
      WHERE a.rank<4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, which also considers a general rule that each product can be related to multiple categories

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    prd.category, rt.product_id, rt.avg_rating, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prd.category ORDER BY avg_rating DESC) AS 'rank'
  FROM (
    SELECT product_id, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
    FROM RateMaster
    GROUP BY product_id
  ) AS rt INNER JOIN ProductMaster AS prd ON rt.product_id = prd.id
) AS result
WHERE `rank` <= 3
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8lkaPgNL)

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * from ratemaster JOIN productmaster ON (ratemaster.id = product.id) order by rating DESC LIMIT 3
```

I think that this should work if I understood it correctly. Hope it works

Comment: i tried this query but it gives only three record. i want top 3 rated product from each category..

Comment: oh my bad , didn't see from each category.